# How to set custom list view item's height...?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a custom list view which contains two text views and on button.
I have customized the button style.
In the list view each row is not fit to show my button properly.
I want to change the list item's height.
How can i do that..?

This is my list view.

```
<ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none" android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:listSelector="#00000000" android:dividerHeight="0px"
        android:divider="#00000000" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" android:background="#00000000" />
```

my custom view xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="#808080" android:text="Subtitle 2" android:id="@+id/text1" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="#808080" android:text="$ 00.00" android:id="@+id/text2" 
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/type10_subbg" android:text="Add"
        android:textSize="20dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#153E7E"
        android:id="@+id/add" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my getView.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    pos = position;
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.type10_sub, null);          
    holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    holder.add = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.add);
    holder.add.setTag(String.valueOf(position));
    holder.add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button b = (Button)v;
            int tag = Integer.valueOf((String)b.getTag());
            System.out.println("Added at "+tag);
            System.out.println("Data = "+((HashMap<String,Object>)list.get(tag)).get("text1").toString());
            System.out.println("Price = "+((HashMap<String,Object>)list.get(tag)).get("text2").toString());             }
    });         holder.text1.setText(((HashMap<String,Object>)list.get(position)).get("text1").toString());
    holder.text2.setText(((HashMap<String,Object>)list.get(position)).get("text2").toString());
    convertView.setTag(holder);
    return convertView;
}
```

Thanks in advance....!

Comment: have you used wrap_content? show us your code! are u using an adapter?

Comment: how are you setting the items in the listview?

Comment: ok great so you are giving the adapter your custom view! This means that your problem is in the custom view. Please let me have a look

Comment: please try to use `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` for the 2 textviews and button. tell me what happens

Comment: @Sherif I tried android:layout_height="fill_parent but no changes...!

Comment: show me `getView` of your adapter? please quickly coz i need to leave

Comment: @Sherif getView updated.

Comment: everything seems correct :S I need to go home! what do you mean "rows  dont fit listview"

Comment: Stop bumping by adding useless stuff. To attract more attention you can start Bounty of the question.

Comment: Please stop with the useless edits just to get this question bumped. I'm locking it for 24 hours just to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`convertedview.setlayoutparams(new Listview.setlayoutparams(width, height));`

First put `LinearLayout` instead of `ListView`

and then edit that to `ListView` otherwise it will not work. This is the trick.

Comment: I am getting "ListView.setlayoutparams cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: first put linearlayout instead of list view and save. Then change that to listview. Ex: new LinerLayout.setLayoutparams....

Comment: `convertview.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(ListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 120));`

Answer (score 1):

set minHeight in R.layout.type10_sub elements

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy to hardcode in a new height for the custom view simply specify the `layout_height` for the highest level item, in this case the LinearLayout.  Below I've shown how to set it to 100dp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    ....
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What if you set the minHeight attribute in the ListView to something bigger like 300?

Answer (score 0):

In linear layout give android:layout_height="100dp" instead of wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
if(convertView == null){
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.type10_sub, parent);   
}
```