# How to set custom list view item's height?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

there are already a lot of questions about this but no one could help me.
I have tried in my class adapter with `view.setMinimumHeigth(minHeigth)` but didn't work.
I tried with `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_note_item,parent);` but the app crashed;
The only one which was close enough was this : 
`View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_note_item,parent,false);` but then the items had the same height but they showed only the first textview and not the second.
How can I do this?

Here's my list_item xml layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/note_item_heigth"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_note"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#808080"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:maxLength="80" 
        />
```

and my listview xml layout:

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list_notes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="@dimen/space_between_items"
    ></ListView>
```

and my class adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_note_item,parent,false);
    TextView title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview_title);
    TextView note = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview_note);
    title.setText("test");
    note.setText("TEST");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you look into this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7533367/3326331)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your LinearLayout must use `@dimen/note_item_heigth` then make your textviews share the given height:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_note"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#808080"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:maxLength="80" />
```

Note: You may need to lower the textSize, for the text to fit the TextView.

---

Otherwise, if you don't care about the List item's height then you can set your LinearAdapter to `wrap_content` and be done with it:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```